# Visual Studio can not start debug session when debuging kernel driver

Tags: c++, c, kernel, visual-studio-2013, kmdf

When I try to debug my KMDF driver from Visual Studio 2013, I get following error

> Windows Debugging Extension for Visual Studio
>
> Could not start debug session, error 8004005: Unspecified error

Before I get the error, it do install the driver on the target machine. Is there any log file where I can see more information?

**Edit 1:**

The host is Windows 7 and the target is Windows 8.1 installed in VMWare ESXi

**Edit 2:**

I have now tested with WINDBG, and get following log output:

> Using NET for debugging
>
> Open WinSock 2.0
>
> Failed to initialize socket.   Error On-2147467259
>
> Kernel debugger failed initialization, HRESULT 0x80004005
>
> "Unspecified error"

I also get following message box:

> Could not start kernel debugging using
>
> net:port=50230,key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX parameters, HRESULT 0x80004005

Comment: Did you end up fixing your problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Now that was a while ago I was doing this, and I unfortunately do not remember what I did to fix it. Good luck getting it up and running :-)

Comment: @8bitcartridge did you manage to fix this ?
I have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember either unfortunately :(

Comment: @GabrielBercea so... did you manage to fix it?:D

Comment: @yuyoyuppe did you manage to fix it? x)

Comment: @Whosdatdev yes, but I don't remember how :D perhaps updating the whole KMDF/VS toolset helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows Debugging Extension for Visual Studio

Could not start debug session, error 8004005: Unspecified error
```

I had no problems and some why Visual Studio 2019 Kernel Debugger has started to throw error above, VS restarts did nothing...

**The solution for me was:** PC reboot